# Pulling data with html and php

Tags: php, html

I'm back again with another, probably simple question. Why exactly is this not working? It connects to the dBase, the html table shows, but no data is showing. It's only displaying $row in each cell and some info about the if statement. I've attempted a few different variations, and in the end, every method I have attempted to utilize to pull information from the dBase has resulted in the same problem. It looked simple enough to me, but here were are.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Table with database</title>
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
color: #588c7e;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 25px;
text-align: left;
 } 
th {
background-color: #588c7e;
color: white;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Id</th> 
<th>First Name</th> 
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Address</th> 
<th>City</th> 
<th>State</th>
<th>Zipcode</th> 
<th>Telephone</th> 
<th>Email</th>
</tr>

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password');

if(!con) {
echo 'Error: Not connected to the server.';
}

if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'MPITdBase')) {
echo 'Error: Database is not selected';
}

$sql = "SELECT  `custID` ,  `custLastName` ,  `custFirstName` ,  
`custStreet` ,  
`custCity` ,  `custState` ,  `custZipcode` ,  `custTX` ,  `custEmail` 
FROM  `Customer`";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>"$row["custID"]"</td><td>"$row["custFirstName"]"</td>
<td>"$row["custLastName"]"</td><td>"$row["custStreet"]"</td>
<td>"$row["custCity"]"</td><td>"$row["custState"]"</td>
<td>"$row["custZipcode"]"
</td><td>"$row["custTX"]"</td><td>"$row["custEmail"]"</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else { echo "0 results"; } 
$conn->close();
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$con`, `con`, `$conn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `.` (dot) operator to concat strings

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>".$row["custID"]."</td><td>".$row["custFirstName"]."</td>
<td>".$row["custLastName"]."</td><td>".$row["custStreet"]."</td>
<td>".$row["custCity"]."</td><td>".$row["custState"]."</td>
<td>".$row["custZipcode"]."
</td><td>".$row["custTX"]."</td><td>".$row["custEmail"]."</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to add [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) i.e.  `.` operator with variables.

Blow is parts of code.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>".$row["custID"]."</td><td>".$row["custFirstName"]."</td>
<td>".$row["custLastName"]."</td><td>".$row["custStreet"]."</td>
<td>".$row["custCity"]."</td><td>".$row["custState"]."</td>
<td>".$row["custZipcode"]."
</td><td>".$row["custTX"]."</td><td>".$row["custEmail"]."</td></tr>";
}
```